# datagridview row click

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datagridview which is filled with data from db and i need to do this:
when click on a row in datagrid all the fields with data from this row will be in other textboxes or something else. How to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

On your `CellClick` event, do int `rowIndex = e.RowIndex`. From there you can do `DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex]` and access all the cells in `row` (or better yet, from your underlying `DataTable`).

Comment: it helped me, and saved some precious time