# how to call a function on click on a gridview row. both functions are placed in script tags in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to be able to call a function when i click on gridview row. how to do it

this is where i handle click on gridview row

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
 // somthing like
  // e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = go to Myfunction;
//OR
 //  e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Myfunction);
   }
}
```

here is the function i wanna call

```
 protected void Myfunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int id = 0;

foreach (GridViewRow myrow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    RadioButton btn= (RadioButton)row.FindControl("RadioButton1");
    if (btn.Checked)
    { 
    id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465457/datagridview-row-click

Comment: Onclick is a client side event.

Comment: i havnt tried. i want the correct form of 
e.row.addatribut(call function on mouse click)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx

I think you need to read up on the controls you're trying to use. The MSDN provides plenty of information on these. You need to state what you're trying to accomplish with your code as your code is incomplete. Maybe then we can suggest a route to take.

Answer (score 0):

**This Should be your code:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
        //Add onclick attribute to select row.
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(YourFunction, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
   }
}
```

**Referance Link:**

[ASP.NET gridview row onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469037/asp-net-gridview-row-onclick)

Comment: I got: No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments

Comment: i got:  Method has some invalid arguments

Comment: i got : 
CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference(System.Web.UI.Control, string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Myfunction);
```

needs an javascript funcation called Myfunction, but it seems that your "Myfunction" is a C# method.

Comment: yeah its C#, Cannot i use it here ?

Comment: You can't call C# methods in javascript directly. I think you should implement if in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void rdb_select_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton selectButton = (RadioButton)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)selectButton.Parent.Parent;
            int a = row.RowIndex;
            foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (selectButton.Checked)
                {
                    if (rw.RowIndex != a)
                    {
                        RadioButton rd = rw.FindControl("rdb_select") as RadioButton;
                        rd.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If u r using listbox with update pannel so,try this,.its working..

```
protected void DDLInclusions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string name = "";
        ListBox selectedValues = (ListBox)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)selectedValues.NamingContainer;
        int a = row.RowIndex;
        foreach (GridViewRow rw in gvwRoomType.Rows)
        {
            if (rw.RowIndex == a)
            {
                ListBox lstRoomInclusions = rw.FindControl("DDLInclusions") as ListBox;
                for (int i = 0; i < lstRoomInclusions.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (lstRoomInclusions.Items[i].Selected)
                    {
                        name += lstRoomInclusions.Items[i].Text + ",";
                    }
                }
                TextBox txtInclusions = rw.FindControl("txtRoomInclusions") as TextBox;
                txtInclusions.Text = name;
            }
        }
}
```