# How to get the value of a record from a datagrid on a double click event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, selecteditem

Basically I have been researching for hours on end and cannot find the answer.
Im using Visual Studio 2012, SQL server, using Visual basic.

I want to transfer the value of record from a datagridtable after it is double clicked so that it will link to a page with the value of the previous values.
I have tried selectedrow ect but still cant get it to work, I have also looked into global variables to see if I could transfer it that way but sadly no luck as I need to be able to get the value.
This is what I currently have, it just displays the first record from the table.

```
Private Sub FlightDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As 

DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles FlightDataGridView.CellDoubleClick
        Dim SelectedRowView As Data.DataRowView
        Dim SelectedRow As CompleteDataSet.FlightRow

        SelectedRowView = CType(FlightBindingSource.Current, System.Data.DataRowView)
        SelectedRow = CType(SelectedRowView.Row, CompleteDataSet.FlightRow)

        Dim BookForm As New ViewFlights
        BookForm.LoadBookForm(SelectedRow.Flight_ID)
        BookForm.Show()
    End Sub
```

In the load event for the 'ViewFlights' form I have this:

```
FlightBookingTableAdapter.FillByFlightID(CompleteDataSet.FlightBooking, Flight_ID:=)
```

However what goes after 'Flight_ID:='

Thanks for any help

Comment: with e.RowIndex you get the row you clicked on...

Comment: allmost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465457/datagridview-row-click only that here the click is used...